# Delete with Where. Procedure deletes everything. Why?

Tags: mysql, sql, jdbc

In my testing environment, I created the following procedure:-

```
CREATE DEFINER=`SC1`@`%` PROCEDURE `sc1_procedure_wipe_perms`(IN UserUUID char(36))
BEGIN
    DELETE FROM subAccountPermissions WHERE `UserUUID` = UserUUID;
END
```

Innocent enough, right?
I call it from Java as follows:-

```
connection = ConnectionMgr.getConnectionToSc1();
rmStatement = connection.prepareStatement("CALL sc1_procedure_wipe_perms(?)");
rmStatement.setString(1, UserUUID);
rmStatement.execute();
```

It deletes everything. I am unsure what is going on here?

Comment: Do you mean that it deletes everything from the entire table? or just everything for that user?

Comment: From the entire table

Comment: Don't give parameters the same name as column names - unless you want the result you are seeing.

Comment: @P.Salmon You should put that as the answer. I believe it's correct.

Comment: Thanks everyone. That's one sneaky gotcha. Glad I've learnt it now rather than working on the real thing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is in the ambiguity between the procedure parameter `UserUUID` and the table column `UserUUID`. The MySQL compiler will ignore the parameter and take the table column for both sides of the condition, which means it will resolve to `true` for all rows.

You need to disambiguate the names, and use a different name for the procedure parameter, for example `UserUUIDToDelete`.